Generating algebraic points on elliptic curves
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbf{Q}$. One has the modular parameterisation
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{H} \to X_0(N)(\mathbf{C}) \to E(\mathbf{C})
\end{align*}
where $X_0(N)$ is the modular curve and the map $X_0(N) \to E(\mathbf{C})$ comes from a morphism of $\mathbf{Q}$-varieties $X_0(N) \to E$. In particular, the theory of CM points on $X_0(N)$ allows for the construction of algebraic points of $E$. The fact that CM points are algebraic follows from the fact that the $j$-invariant function is algebraic at imaginary quadratic numbers (see Theorem 5.2.4 in Lang's book Elliptic Functions).
There is also the Weierstrass parameterisation
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{C} \to E(\mathbf{C}) 
\end{align*}
and one can ask whether this map can be used to generate algebraic points on $E$. A theorem of Schneider (see Corollary III.3 in Lang's book Introduction to Transcendental Numbers) shows that even if $E$ is defined over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$, the image of an algebraic $z \in \mathbf{C}$ will always have transcendental image under the Weierstrass parameterisation.
I have two related questions.

Is there any known way to choose transcendental $z \in \mathbf{C}$ so that the image of $z$ under the Weierstrass parameterisation is algebraic? Some $z$ with this property must exist, but can such $z$ be systematically understood in an analogous way to how CM points on modular curves are understood?

Are there are other situations in which one has a morphism $X \to E$ of $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$-varieties for some curve $X$ over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ that admits a structured supply of algebraic points, like the CM points on modular curves?


Thank you for considering my question.

For 2. Yes Shimura curves by the Jacquet-Langlands correspondence. See Chapter 4 in Darmon's book

@ChrisWuthrich Thanks for the reference, this is a great example of what I was looking for in question 2.

The algebraicity of CM j-values was known well before Schneider's work, and indeed it's relatively easy to prove. (The integrality lies deeper.). Of course, this is not to detract from Schneider's deep theorem, which says that if $3\le [\mathbb Q(\tau):\mathbb Q]<\infty$, then $j(\tau)$ is transcendental.

@JoeSilverman You are of course correct. I've removed reference to Schneider's theorem about transcendental $j$-values since, as you say, it is much stronger than is needed.

Regarding the first question. What kind of characterization you are looking for? The map that you called Weierstrass parameterisation is the exponential map between the Lie algebra and the Lie group $E$. So you want to characterize elliptic logarithms of algebraic numbers. As a more simple question try to think how to describe the usual logs of algebraic numbers. Is there a better description than "the complex number $z$ with algebraic $e^z$"?

@OlegEroshkin I have thought a bit about your question of how to characterise the $z \in \mathbf{C}$ with $\exp(z)$ algebraic, but I can't think of anything besides the fact that $z$ must be transcendental. However, this condition can't be enough; there must be a transcendental $z$ with $\exp(z)$ transcendental as otherwise $\exp$ would be an injection from the uncountable ${0 \leq \textrm{Im}(z) < 2\pi, z\textrm{ transcendental}}$ into the countable set of algebraic numbers. Please let me know if I have made an error.
